# Primefaces datatTable component update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In Primefacs 5.1 update mainPanel inside dataTable I follow two type
@([id$=mainpanel]) and #{p:component('mainPanel')} . My doubt which one best to use?

```
<p:panel id="mainPanel">
<p:dataTable id="studData" ......>
<p:column>
.....
<p:commandButton action="#{stud.saveAction}" value="save" update="mainPanel"/>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable> 
</p:panel>
```

my doubt is which one replace update="mainPanel".
update="@([id$=mainpanel])" or update="#{p:component('mainPanel')}

Comment: `yourContainerNameUsuallyTheFormId:mainPanel`

Comment: @Jorge Campos This student.xhtml include more than one page so I can't use formId:mainPanel.Above two update to be works fine.

Comment: Whats the problem with that? you will update just the datatable!

Comment: my doubt is above the two update(@([id$=mainpanel]) or #{p:component('mainPanel')}) to which one is efficient?

Comment: The one I mentioned in my first comment. There is nothing more efficient than that.

Comment: This page include more than one page that time i use update in dataTable formid:mainPanel it will throw component Id not found.So I use replace update below two it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that... Try `:yourContainerNameUsuallyTheFormId:mainPanel`

Comment: With `:` before the form

Comment: Student projects again? Duplicate: 100% http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735739/primefaces-data-table-style-issue

Comment: @ Kukeltje yes it's student project but not duplicate. I need to just know try which one proper update?