# Primefaces Data Table Style Issue

Tags: primefaces

I have a primefaces table with multiple checkboxes and i used 
  p:ajax for pagination.I placed datatable inside a p:outputPanel
  and whenever i select second page in data scroller i will update
  to main  panel bcoz i want show selected row data into separate   datatable,
  but at that time my datatable style completely 
  collapsed.

I am using primefaces 5.1 version.help me to fix this issue Thanks
  in advance!

This is the sample code of datatable,

```
         <p:outputPanel id="mainPanelId">                                 

           <p:dataTable id="myDataTable"
                        rowIndexVar="tableIndex"
                        value="#{MyBean.beanList}"
                        var="beanVariable" 
                        paginator="true"  
                        rows="#{MyBean.numberOfRowsPerPage}"
                        rendered="#{MyBean.dataTableRendered}"
                        paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink}
                                                   {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} ">
                          <p:ajax event="page" 
                                  listener="#{MyBean.myDataTableScroll}" 
                                  update=":#{p:component('mainPanelId')}" 
                                  global="false"/>
                                 </p:dataTable> 
         </p:outputPanel>
```

[image: Before Data Table:]

[image: After Click Data Scroller]

Comment: Can you add some snapshots of the problem? before and after? Use http://imgur.com/ to upload someone here will add it on your question

Comment: Please create an [mcve]. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Hmmmm student projects again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734893/primefaces-datattable-component-update

Comment: @ kukeltje this is not a student project and i cant put my real project information here that is why i modified like this.This problem is only coming when i give main panel id into p:ajax update otherwise it works perfectly thank you.